# Initializing constant with variable's value

Tags: fortran

```
program main
   real, parameter :: a = 1 
   !real :: a
   !a=1

   res = func(a)
   write(*,*) res

end program main

function func(a)
   real, parameter :: b=a+1  !(*)
   func = b
   return
end function func
```

My compiler complains at the line marked (*). Is there a way to set the value of a constant with a value coming outside that function?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't declare "b" as a parameter since its value is not constant at compile time, since it depends on the function argument.

It is a good idea to use "implicit none" so that you are sure to declare all variables.  Also to place your procedures into a module and "use" that module so that the interface is known to the caller.  As in:

```
module my_funcs
implicit none
contains

function func(a)
   real :: func
   real, intent (in) :: a
   real :: b
   b = a + 1
   func = b
   return
end function func

end module my_funcs

program main
   use my_funcs
   implicit none
   real, parameter :: a = 1
   real :: res

   res = func(a)
   write(*,*) res

end program main
```

Answer (score 8):

@M. S. B.'s answer is fine if run-time initialization is acceptable to you.  If you really do want a Fortran `parameter`, which is set at compile time, then you can do it like this:

```
program main
  implicit none
  real, parameter :: a = 1.0
  real :: res

  res = func()
  write(*,*) res

contains
  function func()
    real, parameter :: b = a + 1.0
    real :: func
    func = b
  end function func
end program main
```

I suspect part of the confusion is due to differences in language.  Often "parameter" is used to mean an argument of a function, but in Fortran it is never used that way.  Instead it means something similar to `const` in C/C++.  So, it is not clear to me from your question whether you really want a Fortran `parameter` or not.

In my example above, the parameter `a` is known inside `func` via *host association*, which is Fortran lingo for nested scopes.  You can also do it with modules, via *use association*, but it is a bit more verbose:

```
module mypars
  implicit none
  real, parameter :: a = 1.0
end module mypars

module myfuncs
  implicit none
contains
  function func()
    use mypars, only: a
    real, parameter :: b = a + 1.0
    real :: func
    func = b
  end function func
end module myfuncs

program main
  use myfuncs, only: func
  implicit none
  real :: res
  res = func()
  print *, res
end program main
```